# Default Image in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I have an optional `ImageField` in my model with a default image. I am using Django Rest Framework for the model api. However when I try to post (post request outside the browser) without images I continue getting the error:`No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.`

`models.py`

```
class Detector(models.Model):
    average_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='average_image/',
                                      default='average_image/default.png',
                                      null=True, blank=True)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class DetectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Detector
        fields = ('average_image')
```

`views.py`

```
class DetectorAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DetectorSerializer
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

i hit the same issue, i had to explicitly mark my image field in the serializer as blank:

```
class DetectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    average_image = serializers.ImageField(source='average_image', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Detector
        fields = ('average_image',)
```

It seems that rest framework is unable to grab it from model or something. After this i am able to POST data to the API using requests like this:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

r = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/detectors/',
    data={'some': 'data'},
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password')
)
print r.text
```

And this is the response, as you can see it used the default from the model field definition:

```
{"average_image": "average_image/default.png"}
```

You can also try to POST with specified file:

```
r = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/detectors/',
    files={'average_image': open('/path/to/image.jpg')},
    data={'some': 'data'},
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password')
)
print r.text
```

Hope this helps.